# "All of these things are not beneficial and (they) do not help her"

Tags: pronouns, negation, repetition

Should I mention the pronoun again in this case?

> "All of these things **are not** beneficial and (**they?**) **do not**
>   help her"

I know that there is already answer about the question "if it's needed to repeat on the pronoun in case that they are in the same position of grammar tense". But in this case it's different because the question deals with case of two different  tenses (in bold).

Answer (score 2):

"They" is optional in this instance and is up to personal preference. However, I would reword the sentence like this:

> **None** of these things **are** beneficial and **they** do not help her.

Note that in the above sentence, "they" should be used, as *None of these things do not help her* is incorrect (double negative).