# Are sometimes vs. Sometimes they are

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> - The following "red" styles are prohibited, but **are** sometimes applied by LibreOffice Writer automatically.
> - The following "red" styles are prohibited, but sometimes **they are** applied by LibreOffice Writer automatically.

Could somebody say which version is correct and sounds better? I tend to think that only the second one is grammatically correct in English, but I'm not really sure, and in my native language it would definitely sound cumbersome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["All of these things are not beneficial and (they) do not help her"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84454/all-of-these-things-are-not-beneficial-and-they-do-not-help-her) It's the same basic question about "Should the subject be explicitly referenced by a pronoun in the second instance?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) The following "red" styles are prohibited, but are sometimes applied by LibreOffice Writer automatically.
>
> (2) The following "red" styles are prohibited, but they are applied sometimes by LibreOffice Writer automatically.

They are both grammatical. It is just a matter of personal preference. Some people prefer (1) over (2) because it is shorter. Some people prefer (2) because they find it clearer since the subject of the second coordinate is explicitly mentioned.